# Skipping projection errors in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, spatial-database

I have a PostGIS query that throws an error somewhere down the line:

```
 SELECT ST_Disjoint(ST_Transform(location, 26910),ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-121.3991535, 37.7458),4326), 26910), 100))

ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (19.9597 50.0466 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)
```

There may have been some error in point collection which is causing this error because there are points in `location` **outside of the projection limits** .

How can I skip records/points in my query that can't be projected??  In other words, how can I skip records/points that are outside of the projection limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26910/, it would seem that the lat/lon limits of this projection (**nad83 / utm zone 10n**) are: -126.0000, 34.4000, -120.0000, 77.0000.

So, one approach would be to use a sub-query or CTE to select only points within these bounds, before passing to ST_Transform, eg,

```
WITH 
   valid_coords (location) AS (
 SELECT
    location 
   FROM 
     some_table
  WHERE ST_XMin(location) > -126
    AND ST_XMax(location) < -120
    AND ST_YMin(location) > 34
    AND ST_YMax(location) < 77
)
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(location,4326), 26910)
  FROM valid_coords
```

type thing.

You could probably do this more generically by getting the projection extents from spatial_ref_sys metadata table.

Also, I did notice that it is possible to put some very invalid coordinates into such a transform before getting the error you reported. However, assuming that you really are working with nad83 / utm zone 10n,then the above should work.